# Can you get the blood pact for the Unicorn?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I've been playing Red Dead Redemption GOTY and I really want to be able to get the blood pact for the mythical Unicorn... I've done all the challenges etc. But it seems there is no way to aquire this.

Could anyone explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no blood pact for the unicorn. However even if the unicorn dies, you can call it over and over again.

Comment: That just seems stupid, but thanks. I was getting kinda frustrated! Why can you get the pact for the other horses and not that one?

Comment: I have no idea why this is. Perhaps it's because the developers wanted to focus the blood pacts to only apply to the four horses of the apocalypse. But that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can keep the unicorn is by hitching it.to find the unicorn you have to have the 4 horeses of the legendary horses and killing the chuprakabra. Now you know